# How to debug a tcl script which is argument to an executable?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tcl

I have a application which takes tcl script as argument. I want to debug tcl script when the application processes it.

My development environment consists of [Dynamic Languages Toolkit](http://www.eclipse.org/dltk) along with [Active state remote debugger -dbgp_tcldebug](http://downloads.activestate.com/Komodo/releases/4.4.1/remotedebugging). I am able to debug the individual tcl scripts with this setup.

I created a tcl project in eclipse and added '`startup.tcl`' and '`argumentScript.tcl`' scripts and added following command to the startup script,

```
set ExecutableName "xyz.exe"

set returnValue [catch {eval exec $ExecutableName "argumentScript.tcl" } result]
```

My debugger works fine with '`startup.tcl`' script. I added the breakpoint in '`argumentScript.tcl`' but it is not working. How can I debug the "`argumentScript.tcl`" script ?

Edit: A solution without using eclipse environment is [Tcl Dev Kit](http://docs.activestate.com/tdk/5.0/Debugger.html#DebugRemote) with remote debugging feature.

Answer (score 0):

you could use tcls introspective abilities to have the script debug itself e.g. using [trace](http://www.hume.com/html84/mann/trace.html)

Answer (score 0):

puts f "debug message" is our all!
Just dump  all that you need in log file. Simple, Stupid and Robust :)